# How create a custom converter in JSF 2?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters

I have this Entity called 'Operation':

```
@Entity
@Table(name="operation")
public class Operation implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Integer id;

    @NotNull(message="informe um tipo de operação")
    private String operation;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Product
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="operation")
    private List<Product> products;

    // getter and setters
}
```

I retrieve the operations this way: (It could be through an EJB instance but just to keep it local and as an example, okay? ;) )

```
public Map<String, Object> getOperations() {
    operations = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    operations.put("Select an operation", new Operation());
    operations.put("Donation", new Operation(new Integer(1), "donation"));
    operations.put("Exchange", new Operation(new Integer(2), "exchange"));

    return operations;
}
```

So I'm trying to get the selected operation in this `selectOneMenu`:

The `productc` is a `ManagedBean` which has a `viewScope`, `productb` is a ManagedBean with a `sessionScope` which has a `product` which is my entity. The product contais one `operation`, so is something like this:

(the letter **c** has the meaning of control, where all operations related about my entity product should be handled by this bean, okay?)

```
Product productc (ViewScope) 
-- ProductBean productb (SessionScope)
---- Product product (Entity)
-------- Operation operation (Entity)
```

The converter is the same as @BalusC is suggest before:

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OperationConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private EaoOperation operationService;

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (!(value instanceof Operation) || ((Operation) value).getId() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return String.valueOf(((Operation) value).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        if (value == null || !value.matches("\\d+")) {
            return null;
        }

        Operation operation = operationService.find(Integer.valueOf(value));
        System.out.println("Getting the operation value = " + operation.getOperation() );

        if (operation == null) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Unknown operation ID: " + value));
        }

        return operation;
    }
```

Which retrieve the operation selected as showed in the log:

```
FINE: SELECT ID, OPERATION FROM operation WHERE (ID = ?)
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
INFO: Getting the operation value = exchange
```

So when I try to submit the form gives the follow error:

```
form_add_product:operation: Validation error: the value is not valid
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to pass a complex object around as HTTP request parameter which can be only be a `String`. JSF/EL has builtin converters for primitives and its wrappers (e.g. `int`, `Integer`) and even enums. But for all other types you really need to write a custom converter. In this case you need to write a converter which converts between `String` and `Operation`. The `String` is then used as option value (open page in browser, rightclick and *View Source* and notice the `<option value>`). The `Operation` is then used as model value. The `String` should uniquely identify the `Operation` object. You could use operation ID for this.

But in this particular case, with such a hardcoded map and a relatively simple model, I think it's easier to use an `enum` instead.

```
public enum Operation {

    DONATION("Donation"), EXCHANGE("Exchange");

    private String label;

    private Operation(String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }

    public string getLabel() {
        return label;
    }

}
```

with

```
private Operation operation; // +getter +setter

public Operation[] getOperations() {
    return Operation.values();
}
```

and

```
<h:selectOneMenu value="#{bean.operation}">
    <f:selectItems value="#{bean.operations}" var="operation" itemValue="#{operation}" itemLabel="#{operation.label}" />
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

But if those values have *actually* to be retrieved from the DB and its size is undefinied, then you still really need a custom converter. You could in `getAsString()` return the ID and in `getAsObject()` use the operation DAO/EJB to get an `Operation` by the ID.

```
@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class OperationConverter implements Converter {

    @EJB
    private OperationService operationService;

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        // Convert here Operation object to String value for use in HTML.
        if (!(value instanceof Operation) || ((Operation) value).getId() == null) {
            return null;
        }

        return String.valueOf(((Operation) value).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        // Convert here String submitted value to Operation object.
        if (value == null || !value.matches("\\d+")) {
            return null;
        }

        Operation operation = operationService.find(Long.valueOf(value));

        if (operation == null) {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Unknown operation ID: " + value));
        }

        return operation;
    }

}
```

Use it as follows:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... converter="#{operationConverter}">
```

As to why it's a `@ManagedBean` instead of `@FacesConverter`, read this: [Converting and validating GET request parameters](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ConvertingAndValidatingGETRequestParameters).

---

**Update** as to the `Validation Error: value not valid` error, this means that the `equals()` method of the `Operation` class is broken or missing. During validation, JSF compares the submitted value with the list of available values by `Object#equals()`. If no one of the list matches with the submitted value, then you'll see this error. So, ensure that `equals()` is properly implemented. Here's a basic example which compares by the DB technical identity.

```
public boolean equals(Object other) {
    return (other instanceof Operation) && (id != null) 
         ? id.equals(((Operation) other).id) 
         : (other == this);
}
```

Don't forget to implement `hashCode()` as well:

```
public int hashCode() {
    return (id != null) 
         ? (getClass().hashCode() + id.hashCode())
         : super.hashCode();
}
```