# NumberFormatException with custom type on primefaces's InputNumber

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I've created a kind of custom type on a JSF project using *PrimeFaces*.
I'd use this type with *PrimeFaces's inputNumber* but I get the error:

> NumberFormatException class java.lang.NumberFormatException
>   java.lang.NumberFormatException   at
>   java.math.BigDecimal.(BigDecimal.java:550)  at
>   java.math.BigDecimal.(BigDecimal.java:383)  at
>   java.math.BigDecimal.(BigDecimal.java:806)  at
>   org.primefaces.component.inputnumber.InputNumberRenderer.formatForPlugin(InputNumberRenderer.java:292)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.inputnumber.InputNumberRenderer.encodeScript(InputNumberRenderer.java:231)
>     at
>   org.primefaces.component.inputnumber.InputNumberRenderer.encodeEnd(InputNumberRenderer.java:124)

In short, I've created a class `MyCurrency` that stores a `double` and extends `ValueExpression`, like the following:

```
public final class MyCurrency extends ValueExpression implements Comparable<MyCurrency>, Serializable {

private Double value;

    private MyCurrency(final Double value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public Double getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public Long longValue() {
        return value.longValue();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(final MyCurrency o) {
        return this.getValue().compareTo(o.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValue(final ELContext context) {
        return new BigDecimal(this.value);
    }

    @Override
    public void setValue(final ELContext context, final Object value) {
        this.value = new Builder().withValue(value).build().value;
    }

    public static class Builder {

        private Double value;

        public Builder withValue(final Double value) {
            this.value = value;
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withValue(final Long value) {
            this.value = new Double(value);
            return this;
        }

        public Builder withValue(final Object value) {
            this.value = Double.parseDouble(value.toString());
            return this;
        }

        public MyCurrency build() {
            return new MyCurrency(this.value);
        }

    }
}
```

And in my bean I've a property with type `MyCurrency`.

When I use it with an inputNumber:

```
<p:inputNumber id="importoDa" value="#{myBean.myAmount}" />
```

I get the error `[NumberFormatException]`.

Any help, please?

Comment: When `formatForPlugin(String valueToRender, InputNumber inputNumber, Object value)` is invoked while debuging, what is the content of the `valueToRender` variable? It must not contain a "," as decimal seperator [which is what you likely did](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Countries_using_decimal_comma). And why do you extend `ValueExpression`?

Comment: I cannot find the method `formatForPlugin`, I extend `ValueExpression` 'cause I suppose that PrimeFaces needs a `ValueExpression` to use it in EL. I'm trying to remove it just now... and it seems the is invoking the `toString()` to get its value.

Comment: `#{myBean.myAmount}` **is** a valueExpression already even if the field `myAmount` is simply of type String, Integer, Double, BigDecimal or whatever. You don't need to extend ValueExpression.

Comment: @Selaron how can primefaces know which's the value attribute in the class `MyCurrency`? Thanks.

Comment: `#{myBean.myAmount.value}` is a valueexpression pointing to the field `value`.

Comment: @Selaron That's the point! I wish I could bind directly to my custom object, but I can easily access to the inner object `value` and solve in this way. Thank you.

Comment: You can bind to your custom object, but that is all it should be, a custom object with a normal jsf converter https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001079/how-create-a-custom-converter-in-jsf-2. Still no need to make it implememt ValueExpression

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if it's a solution for what you are asking, but it seems that you are trying to format the input of your `inputNumber` as currency an compare it's value to another object. It might be easier to store only the `double` or `BigDecimal` value in your bean and format it in the view as currency. You can achieve this using the `symbol` and `decimalPlaces` properties of the `<p:inputNumber>` tag this way:

```
<p:inputNumber id="importoDa" value="#{myBean.myAmount}" symbol="$" decimalPlaces="2" />
```

Hope it helps :)